# VBA code for a pivot table has stopped working

Tags: excel, vba

So I've been using the same code for a few months now to create several pivot tables. Recently all have stopped working showing up with an error that I'm not quite sure about.

```
 Sheets("History Pivot").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Utility!R1C1:R1143C31", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "'History Pivot'!R3C1", TableName:="PivotHist", DefaultVersion:=6
    Cells(3, 1).Select
```

I'm getting a 1004 for pivot table field name is not valid. 
The error is in this line `"'History Pivot'!R3C1", TableName:="PivotHist", DefaultVersion:=6`

Again this error started happening out of nowhere so I'm quite confused, nothing should have changed about where the data is being pulled from.

Comment: Your Pivot is referring to range which doesn't have data which is organized with labelled columns. Check the range `Utility!R1C1:R1143C31` Check if all the cells in row 1 (Column Headers) are filled up...

Comment: Any hidden columns in between by any chance?

Comment: Are you able to manually create a pivot table from your data without encountering any errors?